# Timeout error when accessing list view

Tags: 2010

I'm having problems while accessing a large SharePoint list (more than 5000 items) in SharePoint 2010.
We have already updated the threshold to 10 000 items but at the allitems view we get an error with the correlation ID 3fb21af3-95c1-4562-8b6c-b59da1d1e6db.

The messages about this correlation ID are as following:

> 07/19/2012 11:02:36.59 w3wp.exe (0x1A48)   0x1594  SharePoint Foundation       Database    fa45    High    System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being   aborted.     at SNIReadSync(SNI_Conn* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )     at   SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout)     at   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()     at  System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)  3fb21af3-95c1-4562-  8b6c-b59da1d1e6db

I don't know if this is a good format to post the part of this logfile.
It's all about a list 'Consultaties' in an intranet site. Is there something we can do about this?

Comment: Do you actually require to load the whole data at once? Can't you split your work into chunks of X items?

Answer (score 1):

There are different threshold settings for **administrators** and **regular users** against list view.

For Example :-

If you are logged in as a user trying to access All Items view for a list containing 10,000 items make sure you change threshold settings in the web application settings for users to 15,000 and for administrators to 20,000.

Additionally, you might want to consider increasing listview lookup threshold which is by default set to **8**.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can filter the data by something meaningful into different views and make that filter field an indexed field.

Answer (score 0):

Try the advice from this blog: http://www.sharepointpapa.com/blog/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=20

about increasing the default shutdown time limit for the central administration process model from within IIS.